# Creating a Handle for Manipulation (Unity/MRTK)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

## Question

I develop an application for **Hololens 2** in **Unity (+MRTK)**. I want to **move/manipulate Gameobjects** so i used the ObjectManipulator, BoundsControl and NearInteractionGrabbable Scripts from MRTK plus a Box Collider on the parent.

The hierarchy looked something like this:

- Container

  - Element 1
  - Element 2

With that i could grab the whole container and move everything. Now i want to be able to **select the individual elements inside the container** - but the BoxCollider of the parent blocks/disturbs selecting the inner colliders of the elements.

Thats why i now try to use a **handle**/proxy object (Cube) which applies the interactions to the whole Conainer. The hierarchy can be seen in the next image (just imagine additional elements besides the Handle):
[image: Hierarchy]

Here i have inside the container (AnchoredContainer) now a handle which is a Cube gameobject (HandleObject) with the respective scripts. The scripts are linked to the AnchoredContainer so that moving the cube moves everything (including the cube itself).

## Problem

**The Problem** is now that i seems to be a little bit buggy. I can move/resize the container but it is really hard to grab/select the Rotation Handles and Scale Handles of the BoundsControl. In the next image you can see the flickering when trying to select something on the cube. Also when i resize the cube i loose the resize action as soon as the cube gets slightly smaller.

[image: Error]

What hierarchy do I need or what can I change in the code to use a proxy for the interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As [Zuocheng Wang - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19772221/zuocheng-wang-msft) pointed out the Solution is to set Activation in `BoundsControl` to **Activate On Start**. With this setting, the flicker disappears during focusing and also during movement!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you overlooked the fact that you can assign the `Transform` to be manipulated inside the `ObjectManipulator` script. Take a look in the inspector, the first property of the `ObjectManipulator` component is the `HostTransform` which determines which object will be manipulated.
Using that apporach, you can interact with the sub-elements of the hierarchy while the manipulation, e.g., refers to to top-level parent object.

Does this help?:) If not, feel free to clarify your target.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You are absolutely right, I have also set the HostTransform in the ObjectManipulator as well as the TargetObject in the BoundsControl to my AnchoredContainer. As I said I can move everything together but as you can see in the .gif there is a problem when the child moves the parent (which then moves the child). It flickers and when scaling it keeps stopping because the cube is scaling along with it (and therefore i think it looses the connection to the scaling handle). I haven't encountered this yet when the parent is host and target (and just moves all children) :/

Comment: Just to make sure I get your point: You want to be able to grab the children and manipulate them. By doing so, the whole parent container (inlcluding the children) is to be moved. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly. To have a nice hierarchy i want the proxy/handle to be a child. And this child should be grabbed to manipulate the whole parent container (inlcluding itself and all other children).

Comment: Hi @Alex, I avoided flickering by setting Activation in BoundsControl to **Activate On Start**. You can try it.

Comment: Thank you @ZuochengWang-MSFT ! That did the job. Now it doesn't flicker even when I move it. I will add it as an answer so others can find it. :)